# Why do methods return a value (except void)?

Tags: java, methods, types, return

The following statement is taken from Oracle docs. I can't understand it.

Can you explain it with an example?

> You also can use interface names as return types. In this case, the object returned must implement the specified interface

Comment: Please go through the [**help center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to better understand what questions should be asked here.

Comment: It's similar to the example [on the same page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) `public Number returnANumber() { ... }` Replace `Number` by an inteface e.g. `Serializable` then the returned value can be any class which `implements Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method whose return type is an interface (`java.util.List`). Since you can't instantiate an interface, the method must return an instance (object) of a class that implements the `List` interface (`java.util.ArrayList` in this example).

```
public List foo ()
{
    return new ArrayList ();
}
```